# Is $\lim_{p \searrow 1} \|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)} = \|u\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded, open set and $u \in L^q(\Omega)$ for some $q \gt 1$ (ie. $u \in L^p(\Omega)$ for all $p \in [1,q]$).

Is then
$$
\lim_{q \ge p \searrow 1} \left( \int_\Omega |u|^p \right)^\frac1p = \int_\Omega |u|
$$
true? (In more colloquial terms: Are the $L^p$ norms continuous in $p=1$?)

Sadly, I have no idea how to prove that. (I just *guess* it should be true.)

Furthermore, are there similar results for $p \in (1,\infty)$?

Comment: Try looking for the keywords "log-convexity of p-norms".

Comment: What @GiuseppeNegro said. But the proof is not that hard. Just observe that for any non-negative function $w$ you have $w = w^{\frac12 + \epsilon} w^{\frac12 - \epsilon}$ and then you can estimate $\int w$ by Cauchy-Schwarz. // incidentally if you are actually asking about $L^p$ norms you are missing absolute value signs in your statements. If you are asking about $u^p$ without the absolute value sign I have to ask you to define $u^p$ when $u$ has negative values.

Comment: @user225318: You are right, I forgot absolute value signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assume $u\ge 0.$ For $1\le p \le q, u^p \le 1+u^q \in L^1(\Omega).$ (To see this, think about the sets where $0\le u \le 1, u> 1.$) So by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$\lim_{p\to 1^+}\int_{\Omega} u^p \to \int_{\Omega} u^1.$$

Because $1/p \to 1,$

$$\lim_{p\to 1^+}\left( \int_{\Omega} u^p\right)^{1/p} = \left(\int_{\Omega} u^1\right )^1.$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I forgot the absolute value signs in my question, so (after the edit) I do not need to assume $u \ge 0$ anymore.

Comment: However the answer is actually quite simple, I like that. At first I was not sure whether it is okay to "split up the limit process", but a simple use of the $\Delta$ inequality shows that this is possible here.